# How to get variable in set method

Tags: javascript, class, setter

I have an issue with getting a variable in a setter method when I create a class.
[image: console output]
In the picture above you can see my method "set quest" returns `this` (num 1) instead of `this.questId` (num 2) . How can I get `this.questId` in "set" and what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

```js
  class TestItem {
    constructor(testItem) {
      this.quest = testItem.quest;
      this.answList = testItem.answList;
      this.questId = testItem.id;
    }

    set quest(value) {

      console.log(this , this.questId);
      let questItem = document.createElement('div');
      questItem.classList.add('questItem');
      questItem.textContent = `${this.questId}. ${value}`;
      this._quest = questItem;

    }

    set answList(value) {

      this._answList = value.map((item, i) => {

        let answItem = document.createElement('span');
        answItem.classList.add('answItem');
        answItem.setAttribute('data-value', item.val);
        answItem.textContent = item.answ;
        return answItem;
      });

    }



    getQuestBlock() {
      let questBlock = document.createElement('div');
      questBlock.classList.add(`quest${this.questId}`);
      questBlock.append(this._quest);
      this._answList.forEach(item => questBlock.append(item));
      console.log(questBlock);
      return questBlock;
    }
  }

  function createTest(testData) {
    let testContainer = document.querySelector('#testContainer');
    testData.forEach((item, i) => {
      let testItem = new TestItem(item);
      let questBlock = testItem.getQuestBlock();
      testContainer.append(questBlock);
    });

  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", createTest.bind(this ,testData));
```

Comment: In your constructor, swap the order. Set the setter last.

Comment: wow, thank you for fast answer, it is really work))